# How can I do External API integration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api

I want to integrate an external API with Magento 2, The API has given the code for PHP as:

```
    <?php
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new Http_Request2($apiUrl);
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Key' => 'key',
    'UserName' => 'UserName',
    'Token' => 'Access token'
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guzzle Http client in magento 2 call the API. Every parameters is there but with different name.
Please check the link  Magento 2 DOC link.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/create-integration-with-api.html